# How do I set file browser size in bootstrap 4

Tags: bootstrap-4

How do I make file browser large (or small)
Expect something like **custom-file-lg**

Below is original snippet from Bootstrap 4 docs

```
<div class="custom-file">
  <input type="file" class="custom-file-input" id="customFile">
  <label class="custom-file-label" for="customFile">Choose file</label>
</div>
```

Answer (score 5):

Bootstrap 4 doesn't provide a `lg` file input. What's actually visualized is the `custom-file-label`, not the input. You could add `form-control-lg d-inline-block` to the label, and then a little custom CSS to get the right height:

```
.custom-file-label,
.custom-file-label::after {
    height: initial;
}
```

https://www.codeply.com/go/OYHJuyFLvS

Comment: Thanks, It makes it a bit bigger, but not as other -lg elements. Other label-lg has 48px, but label in your solution has 44px.

Answer (score 2):

I added a custom class (`custom-file-lg`) and a bit of CSS to enable it in Bootstrap 4.

HTML:

```
  <div class="form-group row">
    <div class="col-12">
      <label for="user_name" class="small mb-1 text-70">Logo (PNG or JPEG)</label>
      <div class="custom-file custom-file-lg">
        <input type="file" class="custom-file-input" id="logo">
        <label class="custom-file-label" for="logo">Choose file</label>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

SCSS:

```
.custom-file-lg {
  .custom-file-label,
  .custom-file-label::after {
    padding: 0.5rem 1rem;
    font-size: 1.25rem;
    line-height: 1.5;
  }
  .custom-file-label,
  .custom-file-input {
    height: calc(1.5em + 1rem + 2px);
  }
  .custom-file-label::after {
    height: calc(1.5em + 1rem);
  }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

This is not possible as the upload window is not a browser element.

In regards to Windows, and I'm sure it the same with other OSes:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/app-development/dialog-boxes-overview

> Since these dialog boxes are implemented by the operating system, they can be shared among all the applications that run on the operating system
>
> The common open file dialog box is implemented as the OpenFileDialog class and is located in the Microsoft.Win32 namespace

Comment: I am not about Upload window itself, but file input and button html elements